# Mysql ORDER BY and MIN

Tags: mysql

```
Name      Price  qty
Deen      $11    150
Ann       $12    100
Anthony   $13    250
Anthony   $13    250
Anthony   $14    150

SELECT name, SUM(qty), MIN(price) FROM table GROUP BY name
```

I need to Group by names , sum of qty and only the lowest price as a example

EXAMPLE

```
   Name      Price   qty
    Deen      $11    150
    Ann       $12    100
    Anthony   $13    500
```

any one can help me with sql?

Comment: what's wrong with the given query?

Comment: its not working like example itz giving 650 qty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So that will be:

```
SELECT
  t.Name,
  MinPrices.MinPrice,
  SUM(t.qty) AS SumQty
FROM
  (SELECT MIN(Price) AS MinPrice, Name FROM t GROUP BY Name) AS MinPrices
  LEFT JOIN
    t ON MinPrices.Name=t.Name
    AND
    MinPrices.MinPrice=t.Price
GROUP BY
  t.Name
```

-see this [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3d4d6/1)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    name,
    MIN(price),
    SUM(qty)
FROM
    table
GROUP BY
    name
ORDER BY
    2
```

Look at your query again. I made a table like you proposed, and made that query, it returned almost the result you wanted, except Anthony has sum = 650.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    t1.name,
    SUM(t1.qty),
    t1.price
FROM table t1
WHERE
    t1.price = (SELECT MIN(t2.price) FROM table t2 WHERE t1.name = t2.name)
GROUP BY t1.name
ORDER BY t1.price
```